# IPTables reroute traffic not working

Tags: centos, iptables

I am trying to reroute incoming traffic on my server's port 80 to another server, but it is not working. This is what I tried.  On the host server, I ran these:

```
echo “1″ > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 38.105.20.226:80
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE
```

The server I want it to redirect to is 38.105.20.226:80, but when I go to the webserver that is on the main server, instead of showing the content of the web server on  38.105.20.226:80, it just doesn't load. I am on CentOS.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to specify an incoming interface or destination address in your forward rule (use the `-i` option for an interface, or the `-d` option for an address).

Comment: I have tried to specify the interface, but it is doing the same thing: iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i em1 -p tcp –dport 80 -j DNAT –to-destination 38.105.20.226:80

Comment: Post `iptables -t nat -nvL`.

Comment: I was able to fix it... For some reason echo “1″ > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward did not work, and I had to turn it on manually by editing /ect/sysctl.conf. How can I automatically do this with a command?

Comment: If I am using -d, do I just enter the IP I want to use?